# Display selected rows in datagridview on notification popup

Tags: c#, datagridview

using c#, winforms, sqlite

datagridview has name, startdate, expirationdate columns

I have an application where the user clicks on a button, the click event will take the expirationdate in one of the columns and minus it from today's date which will then make the row light up if the number is < 61 (It must be less than). Basically it highlights rows where the date is close to today's date. Now I want a popup that shows the "name" columns of the rows that were highlighted but I'm not sure how to proceed. If I'm right I need to put it in the for loop and use an if case maybe?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string test = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ExpirationDate"].ToString();
            if(test != "")
            {
                DateTime expiraryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(test); //convert string to datetime
                DateTime itoday = DateTime.Today; //get current date
                DateTime today = Convert.ToDateTime(itoday); //convert string to datetime
        //        String daysdiffstring = (expiraryDate - today).TotalDays.ToString();

                int daysdiffstring = expiraryDate.Subtract(today).Days;
                string daysdifffstring = Convert.ToString(daysdiffstring);

                int daysdiff = Convert.ToInt32(daysdiffstring);
                if (daysdiff < 61 && daysdiff >= -1)             //2 months close to expiry dangerous
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
         }

        PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
        popup.Image = Properties.Resources.information_icon;
        popup.TitleText = "Notification on ending certificates";
        popup.ContentText = "hello world";                         //replace this
        popup.Popup();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add appropriate code in your for and if statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
     {
        var nearToExpiryUsers = new List<string>();
        ----
        Your code
        ----

       if (daysdiff< 61 && daysdiff >= -1)      //2 months close to expiry dangerous
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    nearToExpiryUsers.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"]);
                }
     }
```

Then you need to iterate through each string in nearToExpiryUsers to create a formatted string(as per your choice) and then set this formatted string to popup.ContextText.

```
  foreach (var expiredName in expiredNames)
        {
            popup.ContentText += expiredName + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "iterate through each string in nearToExpiryUsers to create a formatted string"

Comment: I have taken a variable nearToExpiryUsers which will contain the list of users which have close to expiry. Now it is your choice to format and show. I have used Environment.NewLine so that the popup when displayed will have a vertical list of user names. i.e. starting on a new line. You cannot directly assign a List<string> to a popup.ContextText.